# Python: Very large int contains spaces after writing to file

Tags: python, type-conversion, integer, primes

i got a very large int - i add 1 and write it to a file - the file contains spaces at the end - why?

thank you very much.

```
import time
import shutil
import os
from datetime import datetime

current_dir = os.getcwd() 
fileSave = open('primes/m51.prime', 'r')
start_number= int(eval(fileSave.read()))
fileSave.close()
num=start_number
num = num+1
fileFailed = open('failed/prime_failed'+str(time.time())+'.num', 'w')
fileFailed.write(str(num))
fileFailed.close()
```

Content of m51.prime file is:
`pow(2,82589933)-1`

Comment: How do you know that there are spaces at the end and why does it matter?

Comment: I know it because i opened the file in a text editor and it matters because i suspect that integers usually don't have spaces - i need the number to calculate things therefore an integer with spaces is not sufficient- i could trim the spaces but i'm curious what is hapenning. maybe i'll write a program in another language to check the saved number